# Is this a valid proof for why $\{0,1\}^\mathbb N$ is not countable?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

> Show that $\{0,1\}^\mathbb N$ is not countable.

If $\{0,1\}^\mathbb N$ were countable, then there would exist a bijection between $\mathbb N$ and $\{0,1\}^\mathbb N$. This bijection (f) would be a mapping from $\mathbb N \to \text{(set of all mappings from $\mathbb N \to \{0,1\}$)}$ so $f ⊆ \mathbb N \times \{0,1\}$. As $|\mathbb N| > |\{0,1\}|$, $\mathbb N \to \{0,1\}$ is not surjective. Hence, $f$ is not surjective so $f$ is not a bijection. This is a contradiction so {0,1}$^\mathbb N$ must not be countable.

Comment: I already began to edit your question. Click on "edit" and see how it is done...and finish editing. Your argument seems to be very fishy...

Comment: Your argument makes a logical jump that doesn't make a lot of sense to me. And what does it mean $f\colon\Bbb N\times\{0,1\}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is not a valid proof:**

You only proved that any function $g\in\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}$ is not injective. This is correct. However, you haven't proven that a map $f:\mathbb N \to \{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}$ must not be injective.

**Sketch of a correct proof:** Show that $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}$ is bijective to the power set $\mathfrak P(\mathbb N)$. (Hint: Use the bijection $h: \{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}\to\mathfrak P(\mathbb N):g\mapsto\{n\in\mathbb N:\ g(n)=1\}$.) By [Cantor's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_theorem), $\mathfrak P(\mathbb N)$ is not bijective to $\mathbb N$. Thus neither is $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}. \quad\square$